# How do I access in my app content of email created in the app

Tags: ios, email

I have created an iphone app that allows the user to send an email using MFMailComposeViewController. I know that when the email is sent a copy is kelp in the "Sent" emails of the email client. What I wanted to do was also save that data/information to a text file on the iphone (as a log file). I can't find how to access the email information (recipient, body, etc) so as to input into the text file. Can this be done?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

No it can't be done in that you can't access the user's emails.

Your app can log when you present a `MFMailComposeViewController` and what data your app filled it in with before it was presented to the user. But you won't know if they changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have access to the email text in MFMailComposer class. What you can do is, create a view to capture to, cc, subject and message and then launch MFMailComposer delegate and prepopulate all the captured data. The user still has to submit the mail and could change the text all together. The captured data can then be stored within the app.